# Single Sign On (SSO) Standard Web Admin Application

Tags: java, spring-security, single-sign-on, cas, josso

Spring Security, JOSSO, CAS, etc, cares about authentication and authorization.
In most cases admin applications are very similar.

There are schemas for JDBC data sources, but there arent front-ends.

For example:
http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/Database+Setup or http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#appendix-schema

Does anybody know a beautiful and tested third part web admin app to CRUD users and roles on Single Sign On?

Comment: Spring Security itself will be no factor in your search, as the API does not provide write access for auth data and it tries to be ignorant about the actual format/structure of the data.

Comment: @nfechner Ok! But im looking for some third part graceful app that does this job. I think strange re-write every time i need a admin app.

Answer (score 0):

Would the Central Authentication Service project ([CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas)) fit the bill?  It is a Java server that enables single server authentication in large multi-server application environments.  It has a documented protocol that allows multiple servers to share the same authentication environment.

It includes a number of integration points.  Servers in the authentication environment can use spring security integration to obtain the current authentication credentials from a CAS server.  The CAS server itself can provide a login service.  The CAS server can also integrate into common user databases such as LDAP/ActiveDirectory.